# Chrome Extension ( for API Name and Value)

Tags: extension, chrome

I remember seeing a chrome extension which gives the fieldAPI + values of the field populated on the detail records. You can copy the code and run to insert the record in other org or test classes. Can someone pls redirect to me that if You know such things.

```
Example,
Let's name we are on Account Detail page and click the extension. It will populate a window

Name = "Test Account",
Phone = 12312321,
BillingStreet = 123 Main St.
xyz__c = 21321


Field API name and their values.
```

PS. I am not looking for __c("Salesforce API Fieldnames) extension. What I am looking it's a different extension with API name and field values both. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh?hl=en

> This extension not only lets you get API names on a detail page, but
>   also to get all of a field’s data for a selected record. It also lets
>   you import and export data directly in various formats, get object
>   metadata details, and much more.

It was in an article that was the third result of a google search on "Salesforce Chrome Extensions"

Comment: Thanks Eric.  It was something else not inspector.I have used it before for inserting records in test classes. I will post it if I find that...Thanks a lot again..

Comment: @amidstCloud I am at a loss then. It does exactly what you describe right down to the example.

Comment: Yeah. I will use it but in that there was a option to copy field value in clipboard and then paste it new sobject() to insert field. But Yeah. This will solve the purpose if I copy the data table and modify it for insert statement. Thanks again.